# JSP page wont acknowledge my Data Type

Tags: java, eclipse, model-view-controller, jsp, struts

I am using Eclipse Helios with Struts and am having what I imagine is a rookie problem:  for the life of me I have not been able to figure out why my jsp page will not acknowledge my business object .java file.

I think it has something to do with the .java class files as I have been unable to get them to appear in the IMPORTED CLASSES section under my Library Resources heading.  The best I have been able to do thus far is load the class files as a seperate jar (which of course still doesn't appear in the IMPORTED CLASSES section).

Does anyone know why my cart.jsp file refuses to allow me to reference my Cart.java business object?  I get a null pointer error when I try to create the Cart, LineItem, and Product objects below.

Here are some snippets:

`webapp\WebContent\example\cart.jsp`

```xml
 <%@ page import="bo.*, java.util.ArrayList" %>
 <% 
    Cart cart = (Cart) session.getAttribute("cart"); 
    ArrayList<LineItem> items = cart.getItems();
    for (LineItem item : items)
    {
        Product product = item.getProduct();
 %>

   <tr valign="top">
     <td>
       <form action="<%=response.encodeURL("cart")%>" method="post">
         <input type="hidden" name="productCode" 
           value="<%=product.getCode()%>">
         <input type=text size=2 name="quantity" 
           value="<%=item.getQuantity()%>">
         <input type="submit" value="Update">
       </form>
    </td>
    <td>
 <%=product.getDescription()%>
    </td>
    <td>
 <%=product.getPriceCurrencyFormat()%>
    </td>
    <td>
 <%=item.getTotalCurrencyFormat()%>
    </td>
    <td>
       <form action="<%= response.encodeURL("cart")%>" method="post">
         <input type="hidden" name="productCode" 
           value="<%=product.getCode()%>">
         <input type="hidden" name="quantity" 
           value="0">
         <input type="submit" value="Remove Item">
       </form>
    </td>
 </tr><% } %>
```

`Java Resources\src\bo\Cart.java`

```
 package bo;

 import java.util.*;
 import java.io.Serializable;

 public class Cart implements Serializable
 {
     private ArrayList<LineItem> items;

     public Cart()
     {
         items = new ArrayList<LineItem>();
     }

     public void setItems(ArrayList<LineItem> lineItems)
     {
         items = lineItems;
     }

     etc. . . .
```

`Java Resources\src\bo\DisplayCartServlet.java`

```
 package action;

 import java.io.*;
 import java.sql.SQLException;

 import javax.servlet.*;
 import javax.servlet.http.*;
 import org.apache.struts.action.*;

 import bo.*;
 import dao.*;

 public class DisplayCartServlet extends Action
 {
     public ActionForward execute(ActionMapping mapping, ActionForm form,      HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response)
        throws IOException, ServletException
     {

        String forward = new String("success");     ;
         String productCode = request.getParameter("productCode");      

         HttpSession session = request.getSession();

         Cart cart = (Cart) session.getAttribute("cart");  
         if (cart == null)
         {
            cart = new Cart();
            session.setAttribute("cart", cart);
         }

         int quantity = 1;

         // Get product from product code
         Product product=null;
    try {
        product = ProductDB.selectProduct(productCode);         
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
         session.setAttribute("product", product);

         // If product exists, add or remove from cart
         if (product != null)
         {
            LineItem lineItem = new LineItem();
            lineItem.setProduct(product);
            lineItem.setQuantity(quantity);
            if (quantity > 0)
              cart.addItem(lineItem);
            else
            cart.removeItem(lineItem);
          }
          session.setAttribute("cart", cart);

          return(mapping.findForward(forward));
     }

 }
```

Struts.xml declaration:

```
 <struts>

 <constant name="struts.enable.DynamicMethodInvocation" value="false" />
 <constant name="struts.devMode" value="false" />

   <package name="example" namespace="/example" extends="struts-default">

     <action name="cart" class="action.DisplayCartServlet" method="execute">
        <result name="success">/example/cart.jsp</result>
     </action>

   </package>
  . . . . 
  </struts>
```

Link that requests action/servlet:

```
 <div id="cartLink"><a href="<s:url action="cart?productCode=XM123456"/>">Add to Cart</a></div>
```

Comment: Unrelated to the concrete problem, are you familiar with JSTL/EL? This is a pretty trivial job with JSTL `<c:forEach>` and ends in less ugly code.

Comment: I am familiar with JSTL/EL. However, I keep getting another weird uri error that the container can reference the libraries it needs.  I made shure that I download the 2 most recent jstl .jars and it still didn't work.  At this point, I am just trying to get the dang thing to work.  Once it is operational I will polish it off.  But for right now the basic functionality eludes me.

Comment: How do you actually run the sample? In Tomcat/Jetty? You programmed a JSP, that means you need to run/test it in a servlet container.

Comment: Okay, back to the problem, what exactly is `null` while you didn't expect it to be? You didn't provide any details about the cause of the `NullPointerException`. Isn't it just the `cart` which is `null`?

Comment: I have been running everything in Tomcat 7 and the NullPointerException is produced on the line where I create my ArrayList that holds LineItems - ArrayList<LineItem> items = cart.getItems().  When I run it in Tomcat it gives me the NullPointerException; however, in Eclipse it says: **Type mismatch: cannot convert from java.util.ArrayList<bo.LineItem> to java.util.ArrayList<bo.LineItem>** It's kinda whackado?

Comment: first get that nullpointer out of the way...

Comment: Okay, as I guessed, your `cart` is clearly `null`. You just have to make sure that it is not `null`. Create a `new Cart()` and put it in the session before your JSP attempts to access it :)

Comment: That Type mismatch is another story: Are you sure your imports are correct concerning LineItem?

Comment: LineItem is in the same package as Cart and doesn't show any error messages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You expect a cart to be present in a (new) HttpSession. Given an HttpSession exists because you are running in tomcat/jetty and either of these servlet containers will create a session for you.

Now you ask for a cart in that session. Why do you expect it to be there?

```
Cart cart = (Cart) session.getAttribute("cart");
```

You could create one if session.getAttribute("cart") returns null and store it in your session object.

Comment: OKAY . . . don't shoot me at the same time, but I am using a servlet which extends the Struts action controller.  So what is supposed to happen is that the link in the original jsp file activates the my servlet which then creates the cart and attaches it to the session. The servlet then returns a success and the struts forward it to my cart.jsp file which then accesses it.  Of course, in all my wisdom (not really. . .) I 4got to put the action forward in the struts file.  So I just did that . . . and now the bloomin thing tells me that **The requested resource (/webapp/) is not available.**

Comment: So basically before it would display and I would get the error page when I tried to add something to the cart. . . now it won't display at all.  UGGHHH!  I have added the servelt, struts, and original jsp link info to my above post. . .uhm any help is appreciated.

Comment: And of course I still get the same error in my original cart.jsp file in Eclipse which says: **in Eclipse it says: Type mismatch: cannot convert from java.util.ArrayList<bo.LineItem> to java.util.ArrayList<bo.LineItem> **.  So I guess my servlet is not being called to add the cart and product to the session object. . . why not?

Comment: When I **remove** my struts xml declaration that sends control to my action servlet my web app pulls up, when I include it it says that my webapp isnt available. . . gonna try the Eclipse debugger again. . .

Comment: I thought my problem was a reference problem.  Apparently it is not, but rather, a struts problem, as my servlet is supposed to append the product and cart to the session object.  Thanks for your help.  I will resubmit the question differntly under a new post as a struts and not a reference problem.